# For Loop Over a Recursive Call Ocaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml, primes, prime-factoring

I'm working on an implementation of prime decomposition in OCaml. I am not a functional programmer; Below is my code. The prime decomposition happens recursively in the prime_part function. `primes` is the list of primes from 0 to num. The goal here being that I could type prime_part into the OCaml interpreter and have it spit out when n = 20, k = 1.

```
2 + 3 + 7
5 + 7
```

I adapted `is_prime` and `all_primes` from an OCaml tutorial. `all_primes` will need to be called to generate a list of primes up to `b` prior to `prime_part` being called.

```
(* adapted from http://www.ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/99problems.html *)
let is_prime n =
    let n = abs n in
    let rec is_not_divisor d =
      d * d > n || (n mod d <> 0 && is_not_divisor (d+1)) in
    n <> 1 && is_not_divisor 2;;

let rec all_primes a b =
  if a > b then [] else
    let rest = all_primes (a + 1) b in
    if is_prime a then a :: rest else rest;;

let f elem =
    Printf.printf "%d + " elem

let rec prime_part n k lst primes =
    let h elem =
        if elem > k then
            append_item lst elem;
        prime_part (n-elem) elem lst primes in
    if n == 0 then begin
        List.iter f lst;
        Printf.printf "\n";
        ()
    end
    else
        if n <= k then
        ()
        else 
            List.iter h primes;
            ();;

let main num = 
    prime_part num 1 [] (all_primes 2 num)
```

I'm largely confused with the reclusive nature with the for loop. I see that `List.ittr` is the OCaml way, but I lose access to my variables if I define another function for `List.ittr`. I need access to those variables to recursively call prime_part. What is a better way of doing this?

I can articulate in Ruby what I'm trying to accomplish with OCaml. n = any number, k = 1, lst = [], primes = a list of prime number 0 to n

```
def prime_part_constructive(n, k, lst, primes)
if n == 0
  print(lst.join(' + '))
  puts()
  end
  if n <= k
    return
  end
  primes.each{ |i|
    next if i <= k
    prime_part_constructive(n - i, i, lst+[i], primes)
    }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few comments on your code.

1. You can define nested functions in OCaml. Nested functions have access to all previously defined names. So you can use `List.iter` without losing access to your local variables.
2. I don't see any reason that your function `prime_part_constructive` returns an integer value. It would be more idiomatic in OCaml for it to return the value `()`, known as "unit". This is the value returned by functions that are called for their side effects (such as printing values).
3. The notation `a.(i)` is for accessing arrays, not lists. Lists and arrays are not the same in OCaml. If you replace your `for` with `List.iter` you won't have to worry about this.
4. To concatenate two lists, use the `@` operator. The notation `lst.concat` doesn't make sense in OCaml.

**Update**

Here's how it looks to have a nested function. This made up function takes a number `n` and a list of ints, then writes out the value of each element of the list multiplied by `n`.

```
let write_mults n lst =
    let write1 m = Printf.printf " %d" (m * n) in
    List.iter write1 lst
```

The `write1` function is a nested function. Note that it has access to the value of `n`.

**Update 2**

Here's what I got when I wrote up the function:

```
let prime_part n primes =
    let rec go residue k lst accum =
        if residue < 0 then
            accum
        else if residue = 0 then
            lst :: accum
        else
            let f a p =
                if p <= k then a
                else go (residue - p) p (p :: lst) a
            in
            List.fold_left f accum primes
    in  
    go n 1 [] []
```

It works for your example:

```
val prime_part : int -> int list -> int list list = <fun>
# prime_part 12 [2;3;5;7;11];;
- : int list list = [[7; 5]; [7; 3; 2]]
```

Note that this function *returns* the list of partitions. This is much more useful (and functional) than writing them out (IMHO).

Comment: I have edited my OCaml code in the original post to reflect your suggested changes. When I was putting it into the OCaml interpreter, it is bombing on function h because it doesn't have access to `lst`. It's giving me an `Unbound value lst` error. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Your function `h` isn't defined as a nested function. If you want it to access `lst` you need to define it *inside* `prime_part_constructive`.

Comment: I moved it into the function (see above). However, the interpreter is saying that it cannot find `h`. Would that be because I'm referencing it before I use it? If so, how can I change that without destroying `prime_part`'s function definition.

Comment: It's still not inside the function, it's now past the function on the other side :-) I'll write up an example of a nested function.

Comment: Ah ha! I believe I corrected it now to be inside the function with the `in` operator. However, now I have an error `This expression has type 'a -> 'b list -> 'c -> 'd but an expression was expected of type int`. The interpreter is underlining `prime_part n` when I recursively call `prime_part`. Can you have an expression in a function call?

Comment: Of course! You need to parenthesize `(n - elem)`. By the way `in` is not an operator in OCaml. It's part of the `let...in...` construct (for making local variables).

Comment: Would you have a better idea for how to perform my lst+[I] (in Ruby) with OCaml? It's stack overflowing now, and I think that might be the cause - though I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Your problem is that 0 is not a prime, but your list of primes has 0 in it. Change the call at the end to `(all_primes 2 num)`. BTW don't forget the parentheses.

Comment: I fixed the stack overflow issue. When I am calling the `append_item lst elem;`, it is `This expression has type 'a list but an expression was expected of type unit`. What does this mean?

Comment: I don't see a definition for `append_item`. Also, your code seems to assume that `append_item` will modify the list `lst`. This isn't possible, variables and lists in OCaml are immutable. It might be better to start with some simpler examples and open separate questions on SO for them. This dialog is getting too long for the SO format and style.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I truly appreciate it. [Related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42127372/how-to-use-list-map-in-ocaml)