# How to use List.map in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have a list of lists in OCaml returning `[[7; 5]; [7; 3; 2]]`. I know there's a lot of `List` functions in OCaml. I want to print each value out with a plus sign between them like one would do in Python or Ruby. In Python, I do this with `print('+'.join(map(str,lst)))` where lst is the list, str is to convert to a string. How do I do this in OCaml?

Console Input

```
int list list = [[7; 5]; [7; 3; 2]]
```

Console Output

```
7 + 5
7 + 3 + 2
```

**UPDATE**

```
let main num = 
    print_string "Prime Partitions Program" in
    print_linked_list (prime_part num (all_primes 2 num)) ;;
```

I have a wrapper function `main`. It calls all 3 functions for everything to work. However, the interpreter is giving me an unbound value `num`. `prime_part` is a function that gives the linked list back as shown in the console input. `all_primes` is a function that serves as input to `prime_part`. How can I make these functions feed as input to the `print_linked_list` function?

Comment: What's the connection between the input and the console output? `4`, `1` and `6` seem to come out of nowhere.

Comment: They were just random numbers. I have fixed the post to correct this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a function that prints an `int list list` with plus signs:

```
let pll ll =
    let pl l =
        print_endline (String.concat " + " (List.map string_of_int l))
    in
    List.iter pl ll
```

Here's how it looks for your example:

```
val pll : int list list -> unit = <fun>
# pll [[7; 5]; [7; 3; 2]];;
7 + 5
7 + 3 + 2
- : unit = ()
```

Answer (score 3):

The `str.join` method corresponds to OCaml's `String.concat`. So python's

```
"+".join(["1", "2", "3"])
```

maps to

```
String.concat "+" ["1"; "2"; "3"]
```

Same as `join`, the `concat` function will work only on lists of strings, so if we have values of some other type we should map them to string. Unlike Python, in OCaml doesn't have a `str` function that works for all values, as OCaml, in general, doesn't support, so called, ad-hoc polymorphism. So for each type, there is a separate function that transforms it to its values to string representations. For example, for integers, it is the `string_of_int` function. So, the following Python code

```
"+".join(str(x) for x in [1, 2, 3])
```

Can be translated into OCaml, as follows:

```
[1;2;3] |> List.map string_of_int |> String.concat "+"
```

We can generalize it to a function

```
let join string_of_element sep xs = 
  xs |> List.map string_of_element |> String.concat sep
```

With such generic function we can easily solve your problem:

```
let join_ints_with = join string_of_int
let sum_of_ints = join_ints_with "+"
let string_of_equations = join sum_of_ints "\n"
let print_equations eqs = print_endline (string_of_equations eqs)
```

E.g.,

```
print_equations [[7; 5]; [7; 3; 2]];;
7+5
7+3+2
```

Answer (score 1):

Well first let's try to think of a way to take a single list and join it with a `+` character. We can do this by simple recursion. One implementation could look like this:

```
let join_with_plus lst =    
  let rec join lst acc =
    match lst with   
    | [] -> acc
    | n :: [] -> acc ^ (string_of_int n)
    | n :: rest -> inner_join rest (acc ^ (string_of_int n) ^ " + ")
  in join lst ""
```

Now that we have this piece of the puzzle, we just need to apply this to each of the lists in your list.

Here, we can use the [`List.fold_left`](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2011sp/Recitations/rec05.htm) function to iterate over our list of lists, and building up our new list of strings as we go along.

```
let stringify_all_lists lst = 
  List.fold_left (fun acc lst -> (join_plus lst) :: acc) [] lst
```

So our final product would look something like this:

```
stringify_all_lists [[7; 5]; [7; 3; 2]]
(* string list = ["7 + 5"; "7 + 3 + 2"] *)
```